# Daemon with launchd does not receive Call States

Tags: ios, launchd, core-telephony

My iOS Daemon does not receive call state updates, although a handler inline method is defined. It seems to me, that the program does not enter the event loop. does anyone of you have any experience with daemons on iOS, and if yes, can you help me? Here is what i got (compiling it with the appropriate compiler, linking it against necessary libraries and frameworks):

```
@interface CLAppDelegate : NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate>{
}
@end

@implementation CLAppDelegate

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"AppDelegate created!");
        return self;
    }
    NSLog(@"Somehow i lost my pants.");
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"Application launched.");
    CTCallCenter* callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc]init];
    callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* inCTCall) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"CallState: %@", [inCTCall callState]);
    });
};
return YES;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Hello iPhone! (with app delegate)");
    NSString* _appdelegateclassname = NSStringFromClass([CLAppDelegate class]);
    NSLog(@"AppDelegate class name: %@", _appdelegateclassname);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.smr.name"]];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, _appdelegateclassname);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

It compiles and links, and even runs (OpenSSH to iPhone) - but the CallState log is never displayed.
Oh, and also, is there any possibility to run another application (in the /User/Applications/ folder) from that daemon?